# Calculated Column with TODAY() issue

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, date-time

Using the following:

"If Authorization Date is null, calculate the difference between Receive Date and today; If Authorization Date is not null, calculate the difference between Receive Date and Authorization Date"

This formula was tried but generated bad results:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Authorization Date]),DATEDIF([Received Date],TODAY(),"d"),DATEDIF([Authorization Date],[Received Date],"d"))
```

Any insight / help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you getting any error while saving the column with this formula or are you getting wrong(unexpected) results in list view?

Comment: No errors from SharePoint, meaning the formula looks ok. But the results are not correct.

Comment: Can you please add any screenshot or something of list view...what are the outputs of this formula for different `[Authorization Date]` and `[Received Date]` values...and how it is wrong or what are the expected outputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function **DATEDIF(start_date,end_date,unit)** says that if the start_date is greater than the end_date, the result will be **#NUM!**.

So try as follows:

```
IF(ISBLANK([Authorization Date]),[Receive Date]-TODAY(),[Authorization Date]-[Receive Date])
```

Comment: Thank you, Julie! That worked! You made my day!